# Global method prompt and user interface

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, frontend, prompt

anyone know what does mean prompt ID in this code?

```
var ui = ["input","prompt","heading"]; // An array of element ids
ui.forEach(function(id) { // For each id look up the element
ui[id] = document.getElementById(id); // and store it in a property
});
```

After running this code, ui.input, ui.prompt, and ui.heading refer to document elements.
A script could use the global variables input and heading instead of ui.input
and ui.heading. But that the Window object has a method named
prompt(), so a script cannot use the global variable prompt instead of ui.prompt.

Instead, use document.getElementById() to look up elements explicitly. The use of this

```
var $ = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); };
ui.prompt = $("prompt");
```

Is existing prompt who has ID? Why script cannot use global variable prompt?

Comment: I don't understand your question: `prompt` is a pretty legal id, as much as `input` or `heading`. You seem to be confusing with some identical tag names, but they're not involved here.

Comment: Question, needs a re-layout with a clear problem stated, $("prompt"); won't get you the prompt control, $("#prompt"); will do the trick.